# Footer not on the bottom pf page

Tags: css

I have a lot of space under the footer, and this is something that I would really like to get rid of. For some reason, this space only appears in Google Chrome and not in Firefox.

Heres an image showing it.

http://puu.sh/a6XQI/ec07f0ba31.jpg

What I would like to have happen is my content resize according to the screen size. I am not sure if I can do that because I dont have much content, just a few images.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you add your relevant HTML and CSS to your question, along with a live web page or a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any code, I would assume this has to do with the height of you page content being shorther than your window height.  Many people who come from a print design background are often perplexed by the concept that a footer doesn't automatically appear at the bottom of a page.  The position of dynamically sized elements depends on their content, which as you may come to find out, is very frustrating when a client wants a website built BEFORE providing any content.  But I digress.

Assuming the root problem is caused by my former assumption, to achieve what is known as a sticky footer, implement the following to your existing page structions:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/63mp6/

**HTML**

```
<div class="primary">
    <div class="header">
        Header Content
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Main body Content
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Footer content
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #eee;
}
.primary {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header{
    min-height: 100px;
    min-width: 100%;
    background: #aaa;
}
.content {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    background: #fff;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    background: #666;
}
```

What's happening here is you're resetting default styling to the parent containers, forcing them to 100% height of the window and then telling the footer position about of the default page flow to the bottom of it's parent container.  Notice the `position: relative;` attributes on the `primary` and `html, body` definitions.  Those set the tone for their child elements to be relative to them instead of the window.  Without the position declarations, the child elements would position themselves to the highest element with a relative position, which would be the window itself.